# Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/public/ [Laravel - Aws Elasticbeanstalk]

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy my Laravel project on a Elasticbeanstalk server, I keep getting this error:

Frontend error:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Error in the log file:

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/public/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated
>   directory index forbidden by Options directive

I have place .htaccess and index.php in the root not in the public folder.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.ebextensions/01-main.config**

```
container_commands:
  01-optimize:
    command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize"
  02-migrations:
    command: "php artisan migrate --env=production"
  03-cache:
    command: "php artisan cache:clear"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  04-optimize:
    command: "php artisan optimize --force"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  05-permissions:
    command: "chmod 777 -R /var/app/ondeck"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_storage_writable.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Making /storage writeable..."
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage
      if [ ! -f /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log ]; then
          echo "Creating /storage/logs/laravel.log..."
          touch /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
          chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
      fi

      if [ ! -d /var/app/current/public/storage ]; then
          echo "Creating /public/storage symlink..."
          ln -s /var/app/current/storage/app/public /var/app/current/public/storage
      fi

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/laravel-logs.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log


  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
      RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
```

**.ebextensions/02-project.config**

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export HOME=/root && export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /public
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: memory_limit
    value: 512M
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd
    option_name: HttpPath
    value: /worker/queue
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: zlib.output_compression
    value: Off
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: allow_url_fopen
    value: On
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: max_execution_time
    value: 4000
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you placed .htaccess and index.php in the root and not in the public folder?

Comment: @Saurabh If I place .htaccess and index.php into /public folder I get this error :`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` and to access to the website I have to add the public folder to the url (www.example.com/public/).     `PHP Warning:  require(/var/app/current/public/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/public/index.php on line 24`

Comment: Did you ever solve this, getting the same issue now and this is a setup I've used several times in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do this?

1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
2. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
3. Choose **Configuration**.
4. On the **Software** configuration card, choose **Modify**.
5. For Document Root, type **/public**.
6. Apply Configuration

[image]

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes the document root is set as /public.  But still doesn't work.  `- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /public`

Answer (score 1):

This means your server config file is not created properly.

The default config file root is "/var/www/html/public/" but in your server there is no such directory.

You need to do the following.(Respect to apache server)

1. You can edit the default config file ( `/etc/apache2/site-available/default.conf` ) and change the path to your laravel public folder
2. Or You can Disable the default config file (`sudo a2dissite default.conf` inside `/etc/apache2/site-available` directory) and create your own config file and enable it (`sudo a2ensite laravel.conf`).
3. Change the /public and /storage folder permission to `sudo chmod -R 0777 /storage` and `sudo chmod -R 0777 /public`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set permission to public folder with chmod to 755

Comment: Should I do it like this :   `06-publicfolder:
    command: "chmod 755 -R /public"`  ?